# Installing on Toshiba Satellite-z30-b-100: how to increase display resolution

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, toshiba-satellite

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on my laptop (Toshiba Satellite Z30) and I was wondering if there's a way to improve the current display resolution (it's set to 1366x768, but it looks a little blured). Anyone knows if there's a better driver than the one used by default?

Thanks.

Comment: I've used that model at work. Good laptop except for the screen. I think it's the display panel that is just bad: TN with native resolution 1366x768 which is the resolution that you're getting.

Comment: Yrp, you're right. Not sure why, but i really was under the impression that resolution was better with windows... Seems like I was wrong.